# CSV file based on other files data

Tags: python, file, csv, import-from-csv

I want to do this in Python.

Given two input CSV files (data1.csv) and (data2.csv) 
produce a new file (sample.csv) that follows the these specifications:

- data1.csv has headers in first line of the file
- data2.csv has headers in the first line of the file
- data1.csv has more columns than data2.csv
- sample.csv should have all the rows in data1.csv but only the columns that
  appear in data2.csv and in the order they appear in data2.csv

example:

```
 data1.csv
 h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
 0,1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6

data2.csv
h1,h4,h3,h6
0,1,2,3

sample.csv
h1,h4,h3,h6
0,3,2,5
1,4,3,6

 My code:

   import csv
    import array
   import os

  with open('C:\\Users\\nithin\\Desktop\\data1.csv') as f:
     r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    dict1 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r if (row[0]=='h1')}

   print str(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This make the job:

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/data2.csv') as f:
    headerList = f.readline().split(",")
with open('/tmp/data1.csv') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    with open('/tmp/sample.csv', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(','.join(headerList))
        for row in r:
            lineTab = [row[head.rstrip()] for head in headerList]
            fout.write(",".join(lineTab)+"\n")
```